# Validate date (ISO-8601) in request parameters (spring-boot)

Tags: java, date, spring-boot, iso8601

In my controller I have:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/add", method = POST, produces = "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
public ResponseEntity<Object> saveData(@Valid @RequestBody ReceivedDTO dto)
```

In `ReceivedDTO` I have a field:

```
@JsonProperty("end_date")
@NotNull
private Date endDate;
```

I need `endDate` to be in `ISO-8601` (e.g. `2007-04-05T14:30Z`).

Is it possible to validate the `endDate` on the `DTO` level?

Comment: set with pattern which you need @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")

Comment: @Mikhail I'm aware of `@JsonFormat`, but I couldn't make it work with it. Your proposal gives me `JSON parse error: Can not deserialize value of type java.util.Date from String \"2018-05-07T14:30Z\": expected format \"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm\"`

Comment: also you can write your own validator

Comment: in your configuration file: `spring.jackson.date-format=com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.ISO8601DateFormat`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured this thing out.
All I needed to do is to add `@JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmX")`.